# How do I determine if strong key protection is enabled for a certificate private key in Server 2008 R2?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, ldap, certificate

I'm trying to get a Windows Server 2008 R2 domain controller to use SSL with LDAP.  I have a certificate installed, but I'm unable to connect on port 636 via ldp.exe (port 389 works just fine). I verified that the port is open on the firewall, and now I'm working through the certificate requirements on [this MS Knowledge Base article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/321051).

I checked most of the requirements already, but I'm stuck on verifying this:

> The private key must not have strong private key protection enabled.

How can I verify this for a previously installed certificate? The certificate was issued by [DigiCert](https://www.digicert.com).

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a test system at the moment but a Google search produced this article.

[Windows PKI Blog - What is a strong key protection in Windows?](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/pki/what-is-a-strong-key-protection-in-windows)

Near the bottom it states:

> So how can you find out if a key associated with some certificate has strong key protection enabled? One way would be to use certutil.exe -store command that performs a key operation on each certificate it enumerates. If the key has high protection set, the UI will be displayed.

Comment: I run `certutil.exe -store` and I only see the black shell window. This window also only shows 5 certificates, none of which is the certificate I'm trying to use. I'm sure the certificate is installed in the Computer account's Personal store.

Comment: Nevermind. Forgot the "MY" parameter.

Comment: This led me to re-install the certificate, at which time the certificate no longer showed a private key. I did a `certutil -repairstore` for the certificate, and now I can use ldp.exe, but if and only if I use the fully-qualified name of the DC. I was hoping to use this to allow access through our firewall from a specific outside IP that would only connect via IP. Hoping I don't have to get DigiCert to re-issue the certificate.

Comment: I will "+1" this later, but right now as long as the score stays at 0 the question shows on the "unanswered" view.

Comment: Promise kept :)